# setting timeout for response for API connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout

A Rails controller action has a condition whereby, when met, connects to an API

```
Class GuestController
  if @book.quantity - @book.guests.count == 0
     call_book_api
```

Now this particular call should have a response time that will differ from other calls.  A Timeout needs to be set regarding the response of `call_book_api` method with some data (be it positive or negative).

```
@result = HTTParty.post(
  'https://test.co.uk/interface/Book', 
  :body => JSON.parse(@book).to_json,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Host' => 'test.co.uk',
    'Connection' => 'Keep-Alive'
  }
)
```

How can this be efficiently defined at the action level?

Comment: The only generic way use to use `Timeout.timeout` but its a [not a good idea](https://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/). You should instead set the timeout using whatever HTTP client is used in `call_book_api`.

Comment: This also means that the question can't be answered (at least not with a good answer) without knowing how `call_book_api` is implemented.

Comment: the call to the API uses a controller action with `HTTParty.post` to an https address. four headers are defined: `Content-Type`, `Accept`, `Host` and `Connection`.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code to the question instead of making us guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the description mentioned in the post you want to set the timeout when calling third party API using httparty gem.

Use the below mentioned code if it is a get request

```
 response = HTTParty.get('YOUR_URL', timeout: 10)
```

If the it is a post type of request then use the below mentioned code:

```
 response = HTTParty.post('YOUR_URL', body: params, timeout: 10)
```

Comment: is the timeout in seconds?